# How do I remove GitHub pages sub-domain redirection?

Tags: github, subdomain, redirect, github-pages, namecheap

I have a Namecheap domain and it is `somedomain.example`. I accidentally changed the `somedomain.example/blog/` which was in blog repository to `blog.somedomain.example`. Now even if I remove my `CNAME` record and remove the custom URL from the settings in the GitHub page setting, my `somedomain.example/blog/` is still getting redirected to `blog.somedomain.example`.

Is there any way to remove this redirection and use it the default way as it was?

P.S There is no CNAME now in my gh-pages repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar issue. 
In my case I just had the branch: `gh-pages` (e.g. repo.github.io);

```
git branch -> * gh-pages
```

Well what worked for me was to **create the branch**: `master`;

```
git branch master ->
git branch -> gh-pages, * master
git push origin master
```

(in fact I think it's a trick)

Just confirm that there is **NO CNAME file** in `gh-pages` and mainly in the `master` branch.

```
https://github.com/username/repo.github.io/blob/master/CNAME -> 404
https://github.com/username/repo.github.io/blob/gh-pages/CNAME -> 404
```

You can test whether you are still redirecting through `cURL` or `online`;

```
e.g. http://redirectcheck.com/index.php
```

I hope this works for you too.